# Is it possible to do a left join with part of the string?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, amazon-redshift, inner-join

I'm trying to join two tables, but only considering part of the string in table 1.

I have table_1, which looks just like this:

```
product              date_creation
door                 2020-01-02
car                  2020-02-10
house/big            2020-03-15
```

And table_2:

```
product              amount
door/brown           10
door                 100
car/toyota           5
car/toyota/black     15
house/big/beach      3
house/big/beach/old  2
```

I want to get this as a result:

```
product              date_creation      amount
door                 2020-01-02         110
car                  2020-02-10         20
house/big            2020-03-15         5
```

So I want to join the tables considering all possible substrings.

I know I could do something like:

```
select t1.*, sum(t2.amount)
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2
on t1.product = split_part(t2.product, '/', 1)
group by 1,2
```

if everithing was just like *door* and *car*. However, because of *house/big*, I'm stuck without a solution.

Comment: This isn't clear. We have to guess from your examples. "considering all possible substrings" & "just like" don't mean anything. PS Read a definition of JOIN ON. It calculates a CROSS JOIN then returns the rows (input row pairs) that meet the ON condition. What is your condition for the rows to keep?

Answer (score 2):

`like` should do it:

```
select t1.*, sum(t2.amount)
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t2.product like t1.product || '/%'
group by t.product
```

This ensures that the "long" product from `t2` *starts with* the "short" product from `t1`, followed by a slash.

If perfect matches are possible, then the following is safer:

```
select t1.*, sum(t2.amount)
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t2.product || '/' like t1.product || '/%'
group by t.product
```

I was not really comfortable with the `group by` clause (positional expressions and `select *` do not go along together very well). I changed it to `t.product`, which I assume is the primary key of `t1`.